# Failed to connect to telegram via telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to connect to telegram via telethon from Python application

```
proxy_ip = str('188.166.86.173')
proxy_port = str(1080)
with TelegramClient('anon',
                api_id='123456',
                api_hash='1234567890abcdf',
                proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, str(proxy_ip), proxy_port,True),
                connection=connection.tcpmtproxy.TcpMTProxy
                ) as client:
```

I get

> getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None

I don't understand where I use a wrong parameter

Comment: well, proxy_port should probably be an int and you are doing str() to a string.
Also, remove the connection= part you don't need that. and finally, your proxy doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

First ping your proxy to check that if it's working or not,
then change this:

```
proxy_port = str(1080)
```

to this:

```
proxy_port = 1080
```

you should pass proxy_port as an int not string.
and you don't need this `connection=connection.tcpmtproxy.TcpMTProxy) as client:`
so remove it from your code.
now should be fine.
check the documentation for more information about you question:
[Creating a Client in telethonn](https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/basic/creating-a-client.html)